# How can I get my application to continue, only when all async operations are complete?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

In my application, I used to create along string of async operations, which passed in functions like this:

```
public void LotsOfAsync()
{
    DoAsync1( ()=> { DoAsync2( ()=> { doAsync3( ()=> { finalAction();}) } ) } );
}
```

However, now I have moved many of those async operations into separate classes and objects but I want the same results.  Mainly I have moved those async operations into classes which become part of a collection.

I'd like my new code to look like this:

```
public void lotsOfAsync()
{
    DoAsync1();
    for each ( MyClass in Async1List)
     { 
          MyClass.DoAsyn2(); 
      }
    if (allAsyncOperationsAreComplete)
    {
        FinalAction();
    }
}
```

What things do I need to do, to get this to work?  Thanks.

---

Using the Answer below about Tasks, something still seems to be lacking.  The program never continues even after throwing everything into a BackgroundWorker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Task<T>` (using the [Task Parallel Library for Silverlight](http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.Tasks)) - something like this maybe:

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoAsync1()).ContinueWith(_ =>
{
    foreach (MyClass myClass in Async1List)
    {
        tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => myClass.DoSomething()));
    }
    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
    FinalAction();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, does myClass.DoSomething() have to return anything special for this to work?

Comment: No, in fact anything it returns is just ignored in the above example

Comment: It seems that Tasks do not exist on the Windows Phone 7 either :(

Comment: @Bob: I linked a nuget package above that should rectify that

Comment: For future people reading this answer, Windows Phone version of Visual Studio does not support the traditional way of installing NuGet, but you can manually install it.  However, you can't uninstall it.

Comment: I finally was able to attempt to implement this sollution, but it completely blocks the UI thread!?

Comment: I've thrown everything into a BackgroundWorker, but the code never calls FinalAction();

Comment: @Bob: Move the `FinalAction()` call right after `Task.WaitAll()` and remove the outer `.Wait()` - this should give you the behavior you want - Updated answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the update. However for my particular case, since there were multiple httpRequests being made, it still got locked up within the task.  But based on the limited information information I provided in the question, this was definitely the answer I was hoping would work. Unfortunately, it locked up the UI thread too much to be useful for what I was doing.

Answer (score 2):

Im not familiar with wp7, but you may use counter as static field and check if it's equal to 0 in final action.

Every MyClass.DoAsyn2() should fire maybe a event, or any other code to signal that it is finished.

Another option is to move all async to task and call Task.WaitAll

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695.aspx

Comment: Ok this is even better than my tip, it is almost deferred already implemented and ready to use.

Comment: This was the correct answer, but it didn't help me understand how to fire those events.  If you explain those parts I can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at the [CountdownEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.countdownevent.aspx) in .Net 4? This is a signalling construct where one thread will block and only proceed once other threads have completed and called set on the count down event. You initialise it with the number of signals you need before the thread calling `Wait` on the construct will proceed. E.g.:

```
 CountdownEvent countdown = new CountdownEvent(3);
```

will only let the thread calling `Wait` to proceed once 3 other threads have called `Signal`.

So your example would perhaps look something like this:

```
public void lotsOfAsync()      
{
    Int32 numberOfAsyncProcesses = Async1List.Length + 1;         
    CountdownEvent countdown = new CountdownEvent (numberOfAsyncProcesses);

    DoAsync1(countdown); // call countdown.signal() in the async method once complete.

    for each ( MyClass in Async1List)           
    { 
        // call countdown.signal() in the async method once complete.
        MyClass.DoAsyn2(countdown);        
    }   

    if(countDown.Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3))
    {             
        FinalAction();      
    }
}
```

I've also added a timeout where the calling thread will unblock after 3 seconds if failed to get a response from all processing threads. In this case, the final action will not be performed.

You can reproduce this with Monitor/Pulse if you are not targeting .Net 4.

There is a nice example [here](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_CountdownEvent) too. Hope this helps!

Comment: Do you know if the windows phone sdk support .Net 4?  I tried using await and async before but got errors that the keywords were not recognized.

Comment: No unfortunately, however, you can implement the same functionality yourself - see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8879870/syncronizing-actions-in-silverlight

Answer (score 1):

After looking through all the previous answers, I was unable to solve my problem.

Instead what I needed to do, was create custom Events within my classes, which triggered upon a successful completion of the asynchronous tasks.

The website that proved the most useful to me to accomplish this was:  http://www.marten-online.com/csharp/simple-custom-event-handling.html

My final code looked something like this:

```
public void lotsOfAsync()
{
    DoAsync1();
    for each ( MyClass in Async1List)
     {    
          MyClass.PropertyChange += new MyClass.PropertyChangeHandler(Async2Complete);
          MyClass.DoAsyn2(); 
      }
 }

 public void Async2Complete(object sender, PropertyChangeEventArgs data)
        {
            if (data.PropertyName == "AsyncComplete")
            {
                totalAsyncCompleted++;
                if (totalAsyncCompleted >= Async1List.Count)
                {
                    FinalAction();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Note: I would use Interlocked.Increment(ref totalAsyncCompleted) since an increment is not an atomic operation (a read followed by a modify followed by a write instruction and these could be pre-empted).

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard of the Deferred pattern often used in Javascript?

It is simple to work with and very dynamic and you should be able to implement it on Windows phone aswell.

Have a look at this guide
http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/defer.html

Regards
Tobias